# Estilizando o header da pagina com o createAppContainer e o createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Boa noite pessoal, estou tendo dificuldade com **estilização do header**, pois eu criei uma screen principal e nela crei e importei as tabs. Nesse mesmo arquivo eu chamo **3 tabs screen (negócios, contato, email)** e cada uma delas tem a sua respectiva funcionalidades

Entou importando uma imagem da representação de onde eu queria mudar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o meu código de onde eu estou tendo dificuldade para resolver

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, MaterialTopTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Business from './MenuTabBusiness/IndexScreen';
import Contact from './MenuTabContact/IndexScreen';
import Email from './MenuTabEmail/IndexScreen';

import colors from '../../constants/Colors';

function SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar(props) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <MaterialTopTabBar {...props} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const mainNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        'Negócios': { screen: Business },
        'Contato': { screen: Contact },
        'E-mail': { screen: Email },
    },
    {
        tabBarComponent: SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar,
        tabBarOptions: {
            tabStyle: {
                backgroundColor: colors.tintColor
            },
        },
    },
);

export default createAppContainer(mainNavigation)
```

Estou começando com react-native, e estou meio perdido para resolver essa parte do header...

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de resolver este problema.

A primeira seria configurar as "navigationOptions" de cada rota dentro do seu "mainNavigation". Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
const mainNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        'Negócios': { screen: Business, navigationOptions: { headerTitle: 'Negócios' } },
        'Contato': { screen: Contact, navigationOptions: { headerTitle: 'Contato' } },
        'E-mail': { screen: Email, navigationOptions: { headerTitle: 'E-mail' } },
    },
    {
        tabBarComponent: SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar,
        tabBarOptions: {
            tabStyle: {
                backgroundColor: colors.tintColor
            },
        },
    },
);
```

A outra forma seria deixar o "mainNavigation" do jeito que está e fazer essa configuração do "navigationOptions" dentro de cada componente utilizado na rota

```
class Business extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Negócios',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  };

  /* Programação do seu componente */
}
```

Aqui você tem uma link com as opções de configuração do header:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html

Comment: Então, nenhuma desses dois modelos, funcionou, tentei criar um componente igual a segunda opção, e mesmo assim ele manteve aquela barra lá em cima sabe!?

Criei um component, e chamei através da navigation, ele crias as tabs, porém não deixa estilizar o header (parte branca que mencionei na pergunta)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mainNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    'Negócios': { 
      screen: Business,
      navigationOptions: {
        //opcoes dessa pagina
        tabBarOptions: { ... }
      }
    },
    'Contato': { screen: Contact },
    'E-mail': { screen: Email },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      // vai pra todas paginas
      tabBarOptions: { ... }
    },
    tabBarComponent: SafeAreaMaterialTopTabBar,
    tabBarOptions: {
        Style: {  //exemplo
            backgroundColor: colors.tintColor
            labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 }, // tamanho da fonte
            tabStyle: { width: 100 }, // tamanho do header
            style: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }, // cor do header
        },
    },
```

Aqui sao as propriedades do tabBarOptions

- activeTintColor - Label and icon color of the active tab.
- inactiveTintColor - Label and icon color of the inactive tab.
- showIcon - Whether to show icon for tab, default is false.
- showLabel - Whether to show label for tab, default is true.
- pressColor - Color for material ripple (Android >= 5.0 only).
- pressOpacity - Opacity for pressed tab (iOS and Android < 5.0 only).
- scrollEnabled - Whether to enable scrollable tabs.
- tabStyle - Style object for the tab.
- indicatorStyle - Style object for the tab indicator (line at the bottom of the tab).
- labelStyle - Style object for the tab label. Specifying a color here will override the - - color specified in activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor for the label.
- iconStyle - Style object for the tab icon.
- style - Style object for the tab bar.
- allowFontScaling - Whether label font should scale to respect Text Size accessibility - - settings, default is true.
- renderIndicator - Function which takes an object with the current route and returns a - - custom React Element to be used as a tab indicator.

[fonte](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)